# Express each step function involving disjoint intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$h=2\pi \cdot \chi_{(-4,4)} -3\pi \cdot \chi_{[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})} + 4\pi + \chi_{(-1,1)}$

I am unsure how to rewrite this using disjoint intervals. I know that $(-1,1)\in [-4,4)$ and $(-1,1)\in [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$. Finding the new coefficients is what is causing my problems. Is there an easy way to do this?

**My attempt at disjoint intervals:**

$h=$ __ $\pi \cdot \chi_{(-4,-\sqrt{2}]} +$ **_ $\pi \cdot \chi_{(-\sqrt{2}, -1)} +$ _** $\pi \cdot \chi_{(-1,1)} +$ ____ $\pi \cdot \chi_{(1,\sqrt{2})} +$ ___ $\pi \cdot \chi_{(\sqrt{2}, 4)}$

Comment: You mention you are stuck at finding new coefficients but you first need to find new *intervals* that are disjoint (and still capable of expressing the same function).

Comment: i will add them above...ive been trying to work on this problem for a while @ErickWong

Comment: One simple way to get the coefficients is to observe that for instance $\chi_{[1,4]} = \chi_{[1,2)} + \chi_{[2,3]} + \chi_{(3,4)}$.  This lets you expand the wider intervals in the original expression into smaller ones.  However some of your disjoint intervals are problematic: your proposed expression is always $0$ at $x=1$ no matter which coefficients you pick, because $1$ is not included in any of the intervals you've chosen!

Answer (score 1):

Method #1: If you have a two intervals you can always write them as the union at most three disjoint intervals. You can repeat the process to write any finite collection of intervals as a disjoint collection. Now evaluate $h$ on these disjoint intervals to get the required form.

Method #2: Determine the range of $h$, in this case the range has four elements
$r_1,...,r_4$. Then determine $h^{-1}(\{r_k\})$ which will be the union of
disjoint intervals.

The disjoint intervals in this question are
$I_0 = (-\infty,4]$,
$I_1= (-4,-\sqrt{2})$,
$I_2=[-\sqrt{2}, -1]$,
$I_3 = (-1,1)$,
$I_4=[1,2)$,
$I_5 = [2,4)$ and
$I_6 = [4,\infty)$.

It is straightforward to evaluate $h$ at any point of each of these intervals.

Comment: @rover2: I have no idea what your previous comment means.

Comment: @rover2: I added the disjoint intervals above.